# What's the best SQL scheme for this project?

Tags: php, sql

i want to make a php app that let people submit photos/videos/sounds

Now, everything uploaded a record will be added to SQL database with file infos in this way:

```
Photos_table : File_Name | Picture_Type | Picture_Width | Picture_height

Videos_table : File_Name | Duration | Codec

Sounds_table : File_Name | Bitrate | Duration | Codec
```

The App will displays all recent items of all kinds. Is it good to do like the previous scheme, or making all infos in ONE table like this :

```
File_Name | Picture_Type | Picture_Width | Picture_height | Duration | Codec | Bitrate
```

I mean what's the fastest way to gather the infos, i just think the first scheme is more organized than the last one.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Definitely not all in one. If you are uploading media then I would create a table of all media:

> Media_table: ID | MediaPath | ETC
>
> Photos_table : MediaID | Picture_Type
>   | Picture_Width | Picture_height
>
> Videos_table : MediaID | Duration |
>   Codec
>
> Sounds_table : MediaID | Bitrate |
>   Duration | Codec

Look into [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: This is definitely the best way. It's also as close as RDBMSs get to objects with inheritance.

Comment: Thanks durilai, Any idea of how the MySQL query will be to get the infos all the recent media if i use this scheme? & Thanks so much

Comment: @Tom: Join to the appropriate table

Comment: @Tom, look into `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Answer (score 3):

There will not be a big performance difference.  However, using your second method does denormalize your database a bit which is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Use the first scheme - as each table represents a different type with different information.

If you had the second scheme, you would end up with lots of nulls in your table.

Most DB professionals would go with the first one, as it is more [normalized](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer by durilai is the best, if you somehow don't agree with it you can also keep the three separate tables and combine their results in one of two ways:

- 1 query with a UNION.
- 3 queries, combined afterwards with PHP.